# Angularjs and Grunt : unknown provider StateProvider

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have packaged my angularjs webapp with Grunt.
Once deployed on Tomcat7, when I go to localhost:8080 I am getting this error :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   myApp due to:
>
> > Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
> >     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider
> >         at http://localhost:8181/myApp/scripts/9bd11555.vendor.js:5:10748

The webapp works well when I run it from an IDE.
Seems that the problem comes from grunt?
'use strict';

```
angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule', 'tmh.dynamicLocale',
                                'ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCacheBuster', 'ngTable',
                                'ngSanitize', 'ui.select','angularValidator','ui.bootstrap','googlechart','ui.bootstrap.showErrors',
                                'ngActivityIndicator', 'ui.utils','io.dennis.contextmenu'])

    .run(function ($rootScope, $filter, $locale, $interval, $location, $http, $templateCache, $state, $translate, Auth, Principal, Language, Ping, ENV, VERSION) {
        $rootScope.ENV = ENV;
        $rootScope.VERSION = VERSION;
        $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = ' ';

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toStateParams) {
            $rootScope.toState = toState;
            $rootScope.toStateParams = toStateParams;

            if (Principal.isIdentityResolved()) {
                Auth.authorize();
            }

            // Update the language
//            Language.getCurrent().then(function (language) {
//                $translate.use('fr');
//            });
        });


        $rootScope.pingServer = $interval(function(){
              Ping.get();
        }.bind($rootScope), 600000); 



        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $rootScope.previousStateName = fromState.name;
            $rootScope.previousStateParams = fromParams;
        });

        $rootScope.back = function() {
            // If previous state is 'activate' or do not exist go to 'home'
            if ($rootScope.previousStateName === 'activate' || $state.get($rootScope.previousStateName) === null) {
                $state.go('home');
            } else {
                $state.go($rootScope.previousStateName, $rootScope.previousStateParams);
            }
        };

        $rootScope.convertDate = function(dateDisplay){
            if (dateDisplay!=null){
                var day=dateDisplay.substring(0,2);
                var month=dateDisplay.substring(2,4);
                var year="20"+dateDisplay.substring(4,6);
                return $filter('date')(new Date(year,month-1,day), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
            } else return null;
        }

        $rootScope.displayDate = function(myDate){
            if (myDate!=null){
                var day = myDate.substring(8,10);
                var month = myDate.substring(5,7);
                var year = myDate.substring(2,4);
                return day+month+year;
            }else return null;
        }
    })

    .config(function ($stateProvider, $provide, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider, tmhDynamicLocaleProvider, httpRequestInterceptorCacheBusterProvider) {

        //enable CSRF
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'CSRF-TOKEN';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';

        //Cache everything except rest api requests
        httpRequestInterceptorCacheBusterProvider.setMatchlist([/.*api.*/, /.*protected.*/], true);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider.state('site', {
            'abstract': true,
            views: {
                'navbar@': {
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/components/navbar/navbar.html',
                    controller: 'NavbarController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                authorize: ['Auth',
                    function (Auth) {
                        return Auth.authorize();
                    }
                ],
                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('language');
                    return $translate.refresh();
                }]
            }
        });


        // Initialize angular-translate
        $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: 'i18n/{lang}/{part}.json'
        });

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
        $translateProvider.useCookieStorage();

        tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
        tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.useCookieStorage('NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY');
        $provide.decorator('datepickerPopupDirective', function ($delegate) {
            var directive = $delegate[0];
            var link = directive.link;

          console.log(directive);

            directive.compile = function () {
              return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                link.apply(this, arguments);
                element.mask("99-99-99");
              };
            };

            return $delegate;
          });
    })
```

;

Comment: post your code please

Comment: of which files?

Comment: your module file?

Answer (score 1):

You've used `Implicit Annotation` Dependency Injection, this way will not working when you minify your app. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

You can refer this way to define a config or controller to make sure it's working when minify

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$filter', '$locale', '$interval', '$location' ..., function ($rootScope, $filter, $locale, $interval, $location, ...) {
 // do something
}])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$provide', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider' ..., function ($stateProvider, $provide, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider ...) {
// do something
}]);
```